# How to disable "Restored Session" message from appearing every time I run Terminal?

Tags: terminal, zsh, macos

Every time I run terminal on macOS BigSur I see this message

```
[Restored 10 Jun 2021 at 12:18:19]
Restored session: Thu Jun 10 12:18:16 WEST 2021
```

I want the sessions to be restored. I don't want to see this message thousands of times?

thanks

Comment: Thousands?  But really, just leave the terminal open.